# Gmail Filters are tagging emails, but not moving emails to a designated label

Tags: gmail-filters

I have set up filters for many contacts, assuming (I know what they say about ASSUMING) the filtered emails would be archived in the appropriate folder. The emails do show in my Inbox with the correct tag, but not land in the designated folder.

I do want to archive these emails to read later, but how do I get them to automatically land in a designated folder? Nothing is accomplished if I have to physically move a piece of mail with a filter tag.

Comment: Gmail does not have folders, but _labels_ (which I suspect is what you call _tags_). If you don't want to have the message listed in your _Inbox_, you check the _Skip inbox_ box when creating the filter.

Comment: All of my filters are checked with the "Skip inbox" instruction.  For that reason, I am confused as to why my selected emails have "labels" that don't relocate them to a specific location.  I must admit that my misuse of terminology may be causing false expectations.  A tag or a label is a name and as far as I know you can't send a thing to a name.  You send it to a location, which is what most systems refer to as a folder. At any rate, all of my emails must be individually transferred to the desired "labeled location", which renders the whole point of filters pointless.  Open to suggestions.

Comment: If you check both "Skip the inbox" and "Apply the label", it *should* automatically move it to what you called a "labeled location".  Is that not working for you?

Comment: If you're able to post a screenshot (remember to blur out all personal information) it might make it clearer to us how your expectations are failing.

Comment: Thanks Vidar & LevenTech.  I'll work on the screen shot.

Comment: any progress on a solution? I'm seeing the same problem.

Comment: In Gmail, when you click on a label (left side), you are actually searching the "All Mail" folder for messages with that label, instead of opening a folder containing messages.

Comment: Are you looking at All Mail instead of your inbox? That would include anything that is set to skip the inbox.

Answer (score 17):

Filters seem to ignore the "Skip Inbox" option if the message is otherwise marked as "Important".

Possible ways to resolve this are:

- Mark the messages as being "Not Important" and Gmail will eventually learn that these are not important

  [image: Gmail: Mark as not important]
- Update your filter to turn on the "Never mark as important" option.

  [image: Gmail: Never mark as important]
- Or you can tell Gmail not to predict importance on its own.
  Click *Settings > Inbox > Don't use my past actions...*

  [image: Gmail Important marker settings]

  (See also this article in [Google Support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/186543?ref_topic=3394594))

Answer (score 4):

[image]

See the option in the above image, last option 'Also apply filter to matching conversations' mark it. I'had the same issue, I checked this option and emails from specific sender started to land in designated folder.

Comment: This made it work for me!

Answer (score 1):

[image: don't override filters]

Try changing this setting under settings - inbox